# How to find the radius(major and minor) with the given 3 points in an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

I have 3 random points in an ellipse. Is it possible to find the radius of the ellipse?

Comment: No. Since there are two circles containing every three points not no a line, you can take any ellipse which isn't a circle and three points on it, then there will be a circle (i. e. another ellipse) through it having different radius.

Comment: If your ellipse is axis-aligned, you need **four** points to uniquely determine it; if not axis-aligned, you need **five** points. Your problem as it stands is underdetermined.

Comment: @martini: That's not right. Three points not on a line determine a unique circle.

Comment: @TonyK Upps ... you are right of course.

Answer (score 4):

The equation of an ellipse whose major and minor axes are parallel to the Cartesian axes is:

$$
\left(\frac{x-x_{0}}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{y-y_{0}}{b}\right)^{2}=1
$$

As you can see, the equation contains 4 different variables. Therefore, 3 points aren't sufficient to uniquely identify the ellipse.